# How to get the value from URL params in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

Having the following component:

```
import { ChangeEvent, useCallback, useState } from 'react';

export function SearchComponent() {
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState<string>('');
  const updateSearchValue = useCallback((event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setSearchValue(event.target.value);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <input value={searchValue} onChange={updateSearchValue} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

It updates that state value, `searchValue` with the value introduced in the input.

With that value, the URL is updated like this:

```
window.location.hash = searchValue ? `?searchBy=${searchValue}` : '';
```

It add an extra `#` to the URL, before it was `example.com/test`, now it is `example.com/test#?searchBy=my_input` but it's not a big issue.

What I want is to be able modify directly the input and store that new value in the component, so I've tried like this:

```
const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const searchBy = queryParams.get('searchBy');
```

When logged, `queryParams` is an empty object while `searchBy` is `null`.

Is there a way to store the value from the URL if the user is going to edit that value?

Comment: This question seems to be fundamentally the same as your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72203712/update-url-with-a-value-introduced-in-a-search-box-in-react) from 30 minutes ago. Is this a different question?

Comment: I was trying to solve 2 different problems. The first one is related to the hash in the URL that I want to remove, here I want to get the value from URL

Comment: Why are you putting something that belongs in window.location.search into window.location.hash?

Comment: Right, and in both cases it's missing how, or where, you are trying to use the `searchValue` state to update the URL. IMO, it'll be the same answer for both questions. After the user interacts with the input and updates the `searchValue` state, *what* do you want to happen? *What* should trigger updating the URL?

Comment: if that value, searchValue, is updated it will trigger a new search

Comment: So, like in an `useEffect` hook that updates the URL when the `searchValue` state updates?

Comment: exactly, that's working correct and I don't think it is important for the question context. for now it updates the URL but add that extra # (which isn't a huge problem), the problem is that it doesn't work the other way around, when the value in the URL is changed, the state value isn't updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The issue is that `` window.location.hash = searchValue ? `?searchBy=${searchValue}` : ''; `` updates the location hash, thus adding the `"#"` to the URL, and ***not*** the `window.location.search`, which is the queryString part of the URL.

Using `window.location` is also a bit of an anti-pattern as it mutates the location and forces a reload of the page. Better to use the tools available to you from `react-router-dom` to issue a navigation action instead of reloading the entire app.

## Suggested Solution

Using `react-router-dom@5` you will need to use the [useHistory](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory) and [useLocation](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/uselocation) hooks and access the `location.search` value and instantiate your own [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) object. Set the initial `searchValue` state from the queryString, and use a `useEffect` hook to update the search params and issue an imperative redirect to the current route with the updated queryString.

Example:

```
import { useLocation, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

export function SearchComponent() {
  const history = useHistory();
  const { pathname, search } = useLocation();
  const searchParams = React.useMemo(() => new URLSearchParams(search), [
    search
  ]);

  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState<string>(
    searchParams.get("searchBy") || ""
  );
  
  useEffect(() => {
    searchParams.set("searchBy", searchValue);
    history.replace({
      pathname,
      search: searchParams.toString(),
    });
  }, [history, pathname, searchParams, searchValue]);

  const updateSearchValue = useCallback((event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setSearchValue(event.target.value);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <input value={searchValue} onChange={updateSearchValue} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit how-to-get-the-value-from-url-params-in-react]